# asmx Webservice not able to run

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I've created a asmx webservice in an existing project, when i try to run the webservice i got this error "Request format is unrecognized." Help me with this. I'm new to asmx webservice.

What I've tried:
While looking into this issue, there were few solutions to add webservice get and post methods into the webConfig, Tried adding that still could't clear this error. This error will occur during consuming the webservice it seems.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzHKy.png)

Comment: Creating asmx in 2022 is a huge waste. Please read REST API, SignalR, and gRPC and use your time wisely.

Comment: All simple plane jane webmethods in asp.net - for a very long time support REST, or ajax (calls with parameters), or even a direct URL with the parms (rest without headers). See my example below (and no requirement to use a asmx page - you can drop such web methods directly into a existing page). More amazing? That same simple webmethod also supports SOAP calls!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when you setup a webservice, you can do this two ways:

Create a specific page (asmx), or you can simple drop in your functions right into the existing web page, and tag them as web methods.

So say this web page with a First and last name text box. We create a web method to take the two values and return one full name (first + last name). So, lets keep this very simple.

So, our markup will look like this:

```
        <font size="3">Enter First Name: </font>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

        <font size="3" style="margin-left:35px">Enter Last Name: </font>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdAjax" runat="server" Text="Call web method" CssClass="btn"
            style="margin-left:35px"
            OnClientClick="mytest();return false;"
            />

        <br />
        <br />
        <font size="3">Full name result from Web method</font>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" Width="283px" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

And right after above, we have our web service call - we are using jQuery here.

so, we have this:

```
    <script>
        function mytest() {
            tFirstName = $("#txtFirst").val()
            tLastName = $("#txtLast").val()

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AjaxTestFun.aspx/FullName",
                data: JSON.stringify({ FirstName : tFirstName, LastName : tLastName}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rData) {
                    // put results send back into txtFullName
                    $('#txtFullName').val(rData.d)
                },
                failure: function (rData) {
                    alert("error " + rData.d);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

So, when we run, and click on the button, we see/get this:

[image]

And our code behind - on this same web page (no need for a seperate asmx page - but it will work just the same either way).

So, we have this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function FullName(FirstName As String, LastName As String) As String

    Dim sResult As String = ""

    sResult = FirstName + " " + LastName

    Return sResult

End Function
```

Note VERY close how we had to match up the SAME name in the ajax call as the parameters to that web method.

But MOST interesting?

That web method supports:

```
Plain jane REST (with URL parameters)
ajax call web api (with header parameters)
XML soap soap calls!!!
```

So, you actually don't have to create a separate page with web methods.

but, I suppose I could drop above FullName into webservice1.asmx like this:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function FullName(FirstName As String, LastName As String) As String

    Dim sResult As String = ""

    sResult = FirstName + " " + LastName

    Return sResult

End Function
```

So, note how I don't have to make the method "static", since we not dropping the web method into the existing aspx page.

So, now the ajax becomes this:

```
    function mytest() {
            tFirstName = $("#txtFirst").val()
            tLastName = $("#txtLast").val()

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebService1.asmx/FullName",
                data: JSON.stringify({ FirstName : tFirstName, LastName : tLastName}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rData) {
                    alert('back')
                    // put results send back into txtFullName
                    $('#txtFullName').val(rData.d)
                },
                failure: function (rData) {
                    alert("error " + rData.d);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

And note how we can do a simple rest call like this:

[image]

(I put the parameters DIRECTLY into the URL).

so, as the jQuery shows, the simple web method will return json or XML - and it does this without ANY extra efforts on your part.

Directly typing in the URL (a REST call without headers), then it does by default return xml, but you could just do a response.write in the method, and return the string.